# Extracting a line from a .txt file and pasting it in Jenkin email-ext Default-Content Field

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, email-ext, jenkins-email-ext

So I have a Multijob Project in Jenkins and I artifact a txt file after the build has been completed, so nothing special really..

I am using the email-ext plugin to send E-mails with the links to the artifacted files. Now I want to extract the [first] line of this particular artifacted .txt File and include it in the E-Mail using a Script, but since I am totally new to the Jenkins Environment, I'd really appreciate some help.

I know that this can be done with Groovy but I am not sure how to begin.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In groovy you can do this to get the first line and then can use this groovy variable in your mail function.

```
def firstLine  
new File("artifacted.txt").withReader { firstLine = it.readLine() }  
println firstLine
```